# Does $\mathbb{E}e^X=e^{\mathbb{E}X}$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Does $\mathbb{E}e^X=e^{\mathbb{E}X}$ hold? Can we just Taylor expand and use linearity?

Comment: Probably not... E.g. we do not have $\mathbb EX^2=(\mathbb EX)^2$ in general so Taylor will not help us here.

Comment: Taking expectations is something like taking weighted summations, so you’re kind of asking whether the exponential is linear. This alreads suggests a counterexample: If $X$ is just uniformly distributed on $\pm 1$, then $\mathbb E (\exp X) = \frac 1 2 \big(\mathrm e + \frac  1 {\mathrm e}\big) ≠ 1 = \exp \mathbb E X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $X$ be standard normal. Then the expectation of $X$ is $0$. The expectation of $e^X$ is [$\sqrt e$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expectation+value+of+e%5EX%2C+X~Norm%280%2C1%29), which is not equal to $e^0 = 1$.

Linearity doesn't help us get all the way. Sure, if all is well-behaved, we may have
$$
\Bbb E(e^X) = \Bbb E\left(1 + X +\frac{X^2}2 + \frac{X^3}6 + \cdots\right) = \Bbb E(1) + \Bbb E(X) + \frac{\Bbb E(X^2)}2 + \frac{\Bbb E(X^3)}6 + \cdots
$$
but in general $\Bbb E(X^n)\neq (\Bbb EX)^n$, so you can't easily make this into
$$
e^{\Bbb EX} = \Bbb E(1) + \Bbb E(X) + \frac{(\Bbb EX)^2}2 + \frac{(\Bbb EX)^3}6 + \cdots
$$
Of course, the failure of transforming any single term of the power series the way you want doesn't *automatically* mean that the expressions are unequal in value. But it makes it implausible. And the above counterexample shows that they are indeed unequal, at least some of the time.

Comment: Are you sure you can *always* commute infinite series with expectations? If $\exp X$ is dominated by something that's integrable, we can apply dominant convergence. But can you commute them in general too?

Comment: @k.stm You're right, even that step is suspect.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{EX} \leq Ee^{X}$ and equality cannot hold unless $X$ is almost surely constant.

Take any non-constant random variable (like the outcome of a coin toss) to get a counter-example.

When  you use Taylor expansion  and use linearity the problem you face is $EX^{n} =(EX)^{n}$ is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The AM-GM or Jensen'sInequality is: $$\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}{2} \ge e^{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}}, ~x_1,x_2 \in R.$$
Equailty holds only if $x_1=x_2.$
This is nothing but $$E (e^{X}) \ge e^{E x}.$$ so the equality will hold only if the variables are equal and so equality will be trivial here.